# Nested categories URI format on entries

Tags: entries, categories, uri

I have a Category Group that can be 3 levels deep. Each category has its own page and its URI structure appends each category as you go deeper, like so:

`{parent ? parent.uri : 'root-uri' }/{slug}`

Which produces:

`/root-uri/category-1/category-2/category-3`

This all works fine.

I then have a field to assign these categories to an entry. My goal is to create a URI format for the entries that include the hierarchy of the categories it's assigned to. Like:

`/root-uri/category-1/category-2/category-3/entry-slug`

or

`/root-uri/category-1/entry-slug`

What is the proper URI format for the entries to accomplish this?

**Update**

Using `{categoriesField.last().uri}/{slug}` is working, but the `.last()` function is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL format can be a full-blown twig template, so you can use a regular category query to retrieve the category. To replace the deprecated `last()` method, you can use `leaves()` to narrow the category query to only return leaf nodes (categories with no descendants), then use `one()` to return the first matching result:

```twig
{{ object.categoriesField.leaves().one().uri ?? '' }}/{{ object.slug }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `last()` is deprecated, here is the updated version that works:

`{categoriesField.inReverse().one().uri}/{slug}`